# Locally disabling hyphenation in a multicolumn list

Tags: lists, hyphenation

How can I locally disable hyphenation in the following itemized list? I want to disable it only in a specific list in my document.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section 01}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
        \item this is a description of item number one in the list. I would like to locally disable hyphenation in the list.
        \item item 2
        \item item 3
        \item item 4
        \item item 5
    \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output.

[image]

Comment: I've updated my answer with another option that could be of interest for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `\raggedright` inside the environment (to keep the effect local as requested):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section 01}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
    \raggedright
        \item this is a description of item number one in the list. I would like to locally disable hyphenation in the list.
        \item item 2
        \item item 3
        \item item 4
        \item item 5
    \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As **barbara beeton** mentions in [her comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194844/locally-disabling-hyphenation-in-a-multicolumn-list/194845?noredirect=1#comment450861_194845), this might look a little "too ragged" than it should; better results can be obtained using the `ragged2e` package and its `\RaggedRight` command; however, since by default \RaggedRight allows hyphenation, some redefinition of `\RaggedRightRightskip` is needed to suppress hyphenation as requested:

```
\setlength\RaggedRightRightskip{0pt plus 1fil}
```

The following example shows a comparison between the standard `\raggedright` and `\RaggedRight` with no hyphenation:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\setlength\RaggedRightRightskip{0pt plus 1fil}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section 01}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
    \raggedright
        \item this is a description of item number one in the list. I would like to locally disable hyphenation in the list.
        \item item 2
        \item item 3
        \item item 4
        \item item 5
    \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
    \RaggedRight
        \item this is a description of item number one in the list. I would like to locally disable hyphenation in the list.
        \item item 2
        \item item 3
        \item item 4
        \item item 5
    \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is a little more ragged than it might be.  `\usepackage{ragged2e}` and `\RaggedRight` improves the appearance a lot (at least to my eyes).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes; however `\RaggedRight allows hyphenation by default (in the given text it won't be, by changing "I" to "Possibly", you'll receive hyphenated words). Fortunately the package makes provision to adjust some lengths to forbid hyphenation. I've added the necessary code to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: good point -- i keep forgetting that.  (and i'd just set `\hyphenpenalty=10000` to avoid hyphenation if i noticed it happening, but i know that's frowned on by latex purists.)